# Negative lookahead assertion for query in url not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to build regex that will check specific route for if there is "?emial=true" query attached. It should only match positively if there is no "?emial=true" in query. I'm trying to use [Negative lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) but when I paste example below and my regex into tool like https://regexr.com/ then it still shows as match. Somehow last character is not counted in ( 'x' in example below).

```
((\/some-path\/some-path)(-*[\da-zA-Z]*)*)(?!(\?email=true))
```

**/some-path/some-path-1a-dwadsd-waeas-wasd**x?email=true

Can someone help me with this regex? I feel like I am close but can't seem to figure it out :(

Comment: Maybe all you need is `\/some-path\/some-path(?=([-\da-zA-Z]*))\1(?!\?email=true)`?

Comment: you should no use regex for this. search parameter is already solved.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you - worked like charm :)

Comment: I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73038914/3832970) below.

Answer (score 2):

There is already APIs to get search parameters, you should not write regex for it.

```js
let path = "/some-path/some-path-1a-dwadsd-waeas-wasdx?email=true"

let result = new URL(path,location).searchParams.get('email') == "true"

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I needed to pass regex that when matched hides button. I already have class in my project that handles this and I don't want to "fix" it or change it. Just need to build good regexp. But thanks for your answer, I did not know that class. Will read up on it.

Comment: @PawelW. fwiw I highly suspect the framework you're build on doesn't have relevant api. and your code with regex would probably still broken, like if there is more than 1 query parameter.

Comment: it's a small mvp PWA and we are in control of query parameters. So for now, it would work :) But we know it's not permanent solution and will improve over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the quantified part inside a positive lookahead, and then use a backreference to the group value in the consuming pattern part to avoid backtracking:

```
\/some-path\/some-path(?=([-\da-zA-Z]*))\1(?!\?email=true)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uKQsac/2).